# Boot time slow down after installing KDE and Budgie

Tags: boot, kde, 18.04, budgie

After updating to 18.04 I decided to change my desktop enviroment. So I downloaded KDE plasma and Budgie to try them out. I also enabled (VX-t) in BIOS since GNOME boxes was giving me an error when I tried to spin up a VM. Now my boot time is a minute 40 seconds. When I run "systemd-analyze blame" it comes back with:

`16.940s systemd-journal-flush.service
         15.989s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
         15.880s lvm2-monitor.service
         14.754s keyboard-setup.service
         11.447s mpd.service
         10.569s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         10.488s systemd-modules-load.service
          7.866s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          5.778s NetworkManager.service
          5.290s snapd.service
          4.236s thermald.service
          4.191s udisks2.service
          3.831s accounts-daemon.service
          3.822s networkd-dispatcher.service
          3.779s wpa_supplicant.service
          3.718s ModemManager.service
          3.610s avahi-daemon.service
          3.470s grub-common.service
          3.367s lvm2-pvscan@8:3.service
          2.812s resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
          1.889s systemd-random-seed.service
          1.807s lightdm.service
          1.804s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.768s polkit.service
          1.545s apparmor.service
          1.475s gpu-manager.service
          1.282s nmbd.service
          1.266s systemd-resolved.service
          1.207s tlp.service
          1.144s upower.service
          1.080s systemd-timesyncd.service
          1.040s smbd.service
          1.035s packagekit.service
          1.008s rsyslog.service
           949ms dev-mqueue.mount
           918ms apport.service
           901ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
           881ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8236\x2dB737.service
           879ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           872ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           871ms dev-hugepages.mount
685ms snap-core-4206.mount
           676ms bluetooth.service
           663ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           639ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5a55c739\x2d20ac\x2d4b93\x2d954b\x2daa0a6caa40c7.service
           603ms dev-loop0.device
           547ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           527ms snap-core-4486.mount
           477ms boot.mount
           462ms snap-core-4407.mount
           426ms systemd-logind.service
           396ms snap-discord-52.mount
           328ms systemd-udevd.service
           324ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
           288ms plymouth-read-write.service
           278ms systemd-sysctl.service
           262ms colord.service
           244ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           222ms systemd-journald.service
           205ms dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
           188ms ufw.service
           183ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-39.mount
           158ms networking.service
           139ms blk-availability.service
            95ms setvtrgb.service
            88ms plymouth-start.service
            80ms boot-efi.mount
            64ms dev-loop2.device
            59ms user@1000.service
            43ms dev-loop3.device
            40ms dev-loop4.device
            36ms rtkit-daemon.service
            33ms dev-loop1.device
            30ms pppd-dns.service
            29ms qemu-kvm.service
             9ms speech-dispatcher.service
             8ms ureadahead-stop.service
             7ms kerneloops.service
             6ms alsa-restore.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             2ms dns-clean.service
             2ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
             2ms console-setup.service
             2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             1ms resolvconf.service
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
             1ms openvpn.service
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
           536us snapd.socket`

Is there anything I can do to improve my system? I run an 8x Intel Core i7-8550u CPU @ 18.GHZ with 7,7GIB of RAM.